# OS ignoring executable files

Tags: pantheon-terminal

[image: Screenshot that shows that an executable is not "seen" by the system]

I am using Loki 0.4.1 on a 64-bit machine.
When I try to open an executable, or use a shell script that opens it, the system responds by saying that the given file does not exist. However, the output of `ls` and `file --mime-type`shows that the file is there. This has happened several times with different executables.

Is there a way to fix this? I have tried editing the permissions, but it didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

You're sure it has execution rights? (using `ls -l` would give more information).

`$sudo chmod +x wine` should give the file execution rights.

Comment: Also one shoud check mount options. There is noexec mount option that could affect the issue

Answer (score 0):

to run executable files on linux, you have to install wine

`$ sudo apt install wine wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64`

to check that it's installed run `winecfg` (a config windows should appear)

to run an executable file we run the command: `$ wine file.exe`

check [Using_Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Using_Wine)

and one note: normally, a file can be launched by ./file if it has `#!/bin/bash` for bash scripts or `#!/usr/bin/env python` for python scripts ...
otherwise try: `$ bash file` ... or `$ python file`

Comment: and to run skyrim, you need to install directX after installing wine: `$ winetricks xact vcrun2008` ... i think also that skyrim exist on steam... and steam can be installed on linux (check in the AppCenter)